# Mysql relação entre duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom dia, para uma ficha de trabalho foi me dado o seguinte exercicio:

Imagina o seguinte cenário. Pretende-se criar uma base de dados que suporte o controlo de stocks. Sendo que cada produto pertence a uma familia, por exemplo:
Um bloco de folhas A4 pertence à familia de material de escritório. Utilizando o phpmyadmin crie as tabelas necessárias para suportar este cenário.

Já criei as seguintes tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE `produtos` (
  `id_produto` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `produto` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `qtd_stock` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_produto`)
)

CREATE TABLE `familia` (
  `id_familia` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `familia` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_familia`),
)
```

Alguem me pode dar uma ajuda de que relações fazer ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Essa pode ser uma relação `1..n` (um para muitos), o qual um produto deve estar associado a apenas uma família e uma família pode ter um ou mais produtos. Nesse caso, é necessário inserir uma chave estrangeira na tabela `produtos` referenciando a que família ele pertence.

```
ALTER TABLE `produtos` ADD id_familia_fk int(11) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `produtos` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_familia` 
FOREIGN KEY ( `id_familia_fk` ) REFERENCES `familia` ( `id_familia` ) ;
```

Porém, nada impede de que o produto esteja associado a mais de uma família (relação `n..n`). Portanto, se for esse o caso, será necessário criar uma tabela contendo chave estrangeira de ambas as tabelas `família` e `produtos`. Mas acredito que para você, o primeiro caso (`1..n`) atenda.